# Pandas, to_csv () to a specific format

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use DecisionTree 2.2.2 to build a decision tree. https://engineering.purdue.edu/kak/distDT/DecisionTree-2.2.2.html

However, it uses this weird csv format.

```
"","pgtime","pgstat","age","eet","g2","grade","gleason","ploidy"
"1",6.1,0,64,2,10.26,2,4,"diploid"
"2",9.4,0,62,1,NA,3,8,"aneuploid"
"3",5.2,1,59,2,9.99,3,7,"diploid"
"4",3.2,1,62,2,3.57,2,4,"diploid"
"5",1.9,1,64,2,22.56,4,8,"tetraploid"
"6",4.8,0,69,1,6.14,3,7,"diploid"
"7",5.8,0,75,2,13.69,2,NA,"tetraploid"
"8",7.3,0,71,2,NA,3,7,"aneuploid"
"9",3.7,1,73,2,11.77,3,6,"diploid"
```

- The first row, first element should be ""
- The header names should be quoted.
- The index column should be quoted.
- All the symbolic feature should be quoted.

My question is how can I use pandas to_csv function to save a DataFrame into this format? If not possible, can you suggest what would be the best solution?

Thanks

---

This is what I've tried. I convert my columns to string type:

```
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(str)
```

and use index_label when saving:

```
df.to_csv( 'filename.csv', header=True, index=True, index_label='"')
```

but this gives me the following:

```
"""",url,class,length,volume,name,degree,pagerank
......
```

the first element is four quotes.

Comment: Are you sure that that tool actually requires every aspect of that formatting?  Different tools sometimes vary in quoting behavior in CSVs, but it many cases they can successfully read files with other quoting styles (as long as there are no complications like nested quotes).  Does the DecisionTree thing actually fail on a file without the quotes?

Comment: yes, I did try that. Actually the error reported by DecisionTree made me aware of this problem. Good point, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off just to demonstrate that reading this *in* is fine:

```
In [11]: df = pd.read_clipboard(sep=',', index_col=0)

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   pgtime  pgstat  age  eet     g2  grade  gleason      ploidy
1     6.1       0   64    2  10.26      2        4     diploid
2     9.4       0   62    1    NaN      3        8   aneuploid
3     5.2       1   59    2   9.99      3        7     diploid
4     3.2       1   62    2   3.57      2        4     diploid
5     1.9       1   64    2  22.56      4        8  tetraploid
6     4.8       0   69    1   6.14      3        7     diploid
7     5.8       0   75    2  13.69      2      NaN  tetraploid
8     7.3       0   71    2    NaN      3        7   aneuploid
9     3.7       1   73    2  11.77      3        6     diploid
```

You have to use [`quoting=csv.QUOTING_NONNUMERIC`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)* when outputing the csv:

```
In [21]: s = StringIO()

In [22]: df.to_csv(s, quoting=2)  # or output to file instead

In [23]: s.getvalue()
Out[23]: '"","pgtime","pgstat","age","eet","g2","grade","gleason","ploidy"\n1,6.1,0,64,2,10.26,2,4.0,"diploid"\n2,9.4,0,62,1,"",3,8.0,"aneuploid"\n3,5.2,1,59,2,9.99,3,7.0,"diploid"\n4,3.2,1,62,2,3.57,2,4.0,"diploid"\n5,1.9,1,64,2,22.56,4,8.0,"tetraploid"\n6,4.8,0,69,1,6.14,3,7.0,"diploid"\n7,5.8,0,75,2,13.69,2,"","tetraploid"\n8,7.3,0,71,2,"",3,7.0,"aneuploid"\n9,3.7,1,73,2,11.77,3,6.0,"diploid"\n'
```

** `QUOTING_NONNUMERIC` is 2.*

Now, this isn't *quite* what you want, since the index column is not quoted, I would just modify the index:

```
In [24]: df.index = df.index.astype(str)  # unicode in python 3?

In [25]: s = StringIO()

In [26]: df.to_csv(s, quoting=2)

In [27]: s.getvalue()
Out[27]: '"","pgtime","pgstat","age","eet","g2","grade","gleason","ploidy"\n"1",6.1,0,64,2,10.26,2,4.0,"diploid"\n"2",9.4,0,62,1,"",3,8.0,"aneuploid"\n"3",5.2,1,59,2,9.99,3,7.0,"diploid"\n"4",3.2,1,62,2,3.57,2,4.0,"diploid"\n"5",1.9,1,64,2,22.56,4,8.0,"tetraploid"\n"6",4.8,0,69,1,6.14,3,7.0,"diploid"\n"7",5.8,0,75,2,13.69,2,"","tetraploid"\n"8",7.3,0,71,2,"",3,7.0,"aneuploid"\n"9",3.7,1,73,2,11.77,3,6.0,"diploid"\n'
```

*As required.*

Comment: nice use of the StringIO() and thanks a lot for pointing out the QUOTING_NONNUMERIC

Comment: I use astype('S3') for three digits numerical index, astype(str) truncate them to single character.

Comment: @fasttooth does it? interesting/weird, what pandas version are you using? It seems to work without truncating in 0.14

Comment: I think it is a problem with my numpy, my version is 1.6.1. it's time to upgrade. np.arange(20).astype(str) gives me '1' for all double digits.

Comment: @fasttooth time to upgrade! 1.8 is the latest stable! :)